Source for quote from Rebbe Nachman zy"a
Does anyone know where the source is for the quote, "Remember: Things can go from the very worst to the very best in just the blink of an eye", I don't think this is an exact quote but if anyone knows where there is a source for some thing close to this, would much appreciate it.

ישועת ה׳ כהרף עין

Cf. this, though the origin of the phrase seems older than Rebbe Nachman according to Hebrew Wikipedia
